# Has any Vedantin criticized this teaching of the Buddha?

Tags: vedanta, buddhism, consciousness

According to Vedanta, a single self or jIva is the seat of consciousness. jIva as a single unit, is not further divisible.

Buddhism, on the other hand, does not subscribe to the doctrine of a permanent self. And in one of the suttas of Buddhism, the Buddha classifies consciousness into eye-consciousness, ear-consciousness and so on. (The Pali word used here is viññāṇa).

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.038.than.html

> "Consciousness, monks, is classified simply by the requisite condition in dependence on which it arises. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the eye & forms is classified simply as eye-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the ear & sounds is classified simply as ear-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the nose & aromas is classified simply as nose-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the tongue & flavors is classified simply as tongue-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the body & tactile sensations is classified simply as body-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the intellect & ideas is classified simply as intellect-consciousness.
>
> "Just as fire is classified simply by whatever requisite condition in dependence on which it burns — a fire that burns in dependence on wood is classified simply as a wood-fire, a fire that burns in dependence on wood-chips is classified simply as a wood-chip-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on grass is classified simply as a grass-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on cow-dung is classified simply as a cow-dung-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on chaff is classified simply as a chaff-fire; a fire that burns in dependence on rubbish is classified simply as a rubbish-fire — in the same way, consciousness is classified simply by the requisite condition in dependence on which it arises. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the eye & forms is classified simply as eye-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the ear & sounds is classified simply as ear-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the nose & aromas is classified simply as nose-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the tongue & flavors is classified simply as tongue-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the body & tactile sensations is classified simply as body-consciousness. Consciousness that arises in dependence on the intellect & ideas is classified simply as intellect-consciousness.

This Buddhist classification of consciousness into multiple individual consciousnesses would go against the teaching of the Vedanta, which considers consciousness as one. Moreover, for Vedanta, consciousness does not depend on eyes, ears etc.

Here is my question: Has any Vedantin criticized this Buddhist classification of consciousness into many and the dependance of consciousness on the senses? If yes, what were the arguments used to criticize Buddhism and defend the Vedantic notion of consciousness?

Comment: please see VedAntasArah 134, 135

Comment: @commonman I checked. I am not sure it is addressing the question. The Buddhist viewpoint is not even correctly represented. In 131, it incorrectly describes one view of Buddhists as - sunya is self.

Comment: The Bengali subcommentary by Swami Amritatvananda from Udbodhan is satisfactory to me, as it shows that organs are not separately conscious and are guided by buddhi and buddhi is related to Atma and ultimately everything is linked to the Supreme Nondual Consciousness.

Comment: @commonman The Buddha is also not saying that organs are separately conscious. He is talking of consciousness arising in dependance on the senses and objects.

Comment: yes, but did He accept the existence of the Nondual Supreme Consciousness?

Comment: If He did not believe in AtmA, how did He explain the rebirth btw?

Comment: @commonman Not as far as I know. Consciousness is not independent in Buddhism. It arises dependant on other factors.

Comment: @commonman He did not believe in a **permanent** Atman. But he does not disagree with the notion of an empirical self-hood.

Comment: okay I see.Sri Krishnaprem points out that neither Sankar nor Buddha is incorrect.

Comment: In certain Buddhist texts, specifically the Tathagatagarbha Sutras, Buddha did speak of a permanent Self but it's still not quite the same as Vedantic Atman.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Tathagathagarbha is a later Mahayana concept, where as my question is related to the original Pali canon.